# Parse string with nested brackets

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

String to parse (without spaces):

```
 "instrumentalist  (  bass  (upright  , fretless , 5-string ) ,  guitar  ( electric , acoustic ) ,  trumpet  ),  teacher  ,  songwriter,    producer"
```

I need to get this structure in Ruby

```
["instrumentalist",[["bass",["upright","fretless","5-string"]],["guitar",["electric","acoustic"]],["trumpet"]],["teacher"],["songwriter"],["producer"]]
```

Because of nested `(`,`)` and `,` `String#partition` couldn't help me. I don't really know is there a fancy RegEx that could extract such type of strings. Or do I have to go with a lexer?

Comment: Your question is very vague. You need to be a lot more specific about what you're trying to accomplish. What do you mean by "extract" and "such type of strings"? Are you trying to do a replacement? If so, what do you want to replace with what? Are you trying to match particular parts of the string? If so, what are you trying to match. Be as clear as possible about what the criteria are and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Where did "5-string" come from? Also, this seems like you need an actual parser.

Comment: Looks like you could do this with string scanner

Comment: With or without a lexer, it is impossible. You cannot get the strings `"5-string"` or `"stud"` from nowhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A regex on its own isn't the right sort of thing for this type of problem, even though the basic process is simple: walk through your string looking for commas or brackets. When you find a comma add the previous read characters to the current nesting. When you find an open bracket then your nesting level goes up by 1, when you find a close bracket decrease it.

StringScanner is designed for this sort of stuff as it allows us to walk through the string while maintaining, some state, in this case a stack that mirrors your opening and closing brackets. Something like this does the job for me

```ruby
require 'strscan'

def parse input
  scanner = StringScanner.new input
  stack = [[]]
  while string = scanner.scan(/[^(),]+/)
    case scanner.scan /[(),]+/
    when '('
      new_nesting = [string, []]
      stack.last << new_nesting
      stack << new_nesting[1]
    when ')'
      scanner.scan(/,/)
      stack.last << string
      stack.pop
    else
      stack.last << string
    end
  end
  stack.last
end
```

Comment: This is not an answer the question: [Do] I have to go with [a] lexer?

Comment: Gives the answer : `["upright", "fretless"]` for string `bass(upright,fretless)`

Comment: Ah yes, not handling that case properly.